# Shows only the first letter of a sentence/word when echoed in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display the date from the database using the following code.

```
<?php 
   $query_course = mysqli_query($databaseConnection,"SELECT * FROM grading WHERE courseid=".$courseid);
   $count=0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_course))
   {
       $gradename[$count]= $row['gradingname'];
       $percentage[$count]= $row['percentage'];
       $date[$count]= $row['date'];
       ?>
       <tr>
       <td><?php echo $gradename[$count]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $percentage[$count]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $date[$count]; ?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php $count++; 
     } ?>
```

But it displays only the first letter/digit for the date. Database looks fine. What might be the problem?

Comment: why not just echo the values directly like `echo $row['gradingname'];`

Comment: I will have more than one row for this query.

Comment: Yes thats why you have a while loop.

Comment: What does `var_dump($row); exit;` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that would explain this is if `$gradename` etc. were initialised as strings. E.g.:

```
$foo = '';
$foo[0] = 'bar';
echo $foo[0]; // b
```

Make sure you initialise your variables as arrays before the loop:

```
$gradename = array();
...
```

(I'd question the usefulness of those extra arrays to begin with, but that's outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: It works fine. :) Thanks But why should I do this only for a particular variable? (say $date)

Comment: I don't understand your question...!?

Answer (score -2):

it displays the first digit because you use the count as index. Since the count is 0 it display just the first digit from date. Remove the $count and echo the $row['date'].

Comment: The OP is using the index to output, but they're also using the index to assign the value in the first place.

Comment: He can echo the date without assign $row['date'] to another variable and without using the $count as index.

Comment: maybe later he want to use that array.

Comment: in this case you are right. but i explained why its displays just first digit.he can play around and choose what best meet his requirements.